# Grant role on button click discord.py

Tags: python, button, discord, discord.py, roles

```py
#rules embed is made earlier on
rulesbutton = Button(label="Accept Rules", custom_id = "rulesbutton", color="green", emoji="")
    await ctx.send(embed=rules, components=[rulesbutton])

    interaction = await client.wait_for("button_click", check= lambda i: i.custom_id == 'rulesbutton')
    await interaction.send(content="Role Added!", ephermal=True)
```

Comment: What exactly is your issue? Please describe any errors you are receiving or how the program behaviour deviates from what you expected

Comment: A traceback and the library you use would be helpful though